# how to write a dockerfile to run a sbt project in container

Tags: docker, sbt

I want to write a **dockerfile** manually without using any sbt plugins.
I am using sbt 0.13.8. I looked at **dockerfile reference** but could not get enough insights for my requirement. A demo would be extremely helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean write a Dockerfile producing an image able to run an sbt project, you can take a look at [`William-Yeh/docker-sbt`](https://github.com/William-Yeh/docker-sbt/blob/master/Dockerfile):

```
# Sbt on Java 7
#
# URL: https://github.com/William-Yeh/docker-sbt
#
# @see http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Manual-Installation.html
#
# Version     0.7

FROM williamyeh/java7
MAINTAINER William Yeh <william.pjyeh@gmail.com>


ENV SBT_VERSION  0.13.8
ENV SBT_JAR      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/$SBT_VERSION/sbt-launch.jar


ADD  $SBT_JAR  /usr/local/bin/sbt-launch.jar  
COPY sbt.sh    /usr/local/bin/sbt

RUN echo "==> fetch all sbt jars from Maven repo..."       && \
    echo "==> [CAUTION] this may take several minutes!!!"  && \
    sbt


VOLUME [ "/app" ]
WORKDIR /app


# Define default command.
ENTRYPOINT ["sbt"]
CMD ["--version"]
```

Comment: @oblivion no problem. Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Thanks :) hey, I need more help regarding the Commands that are used in the given dockerfile.  Lets say i have a folder , Workspace.  Then inside Workspace, i have a dockerfile named as "mydockerfile" and a sbt project named "demo".  Inside demo > src > main > scala , i have a runnable object :  object Runner extends App {  println("Hello World")
}  
Now, how should i provide value for dockerfile INSTRUCTIONS such as :  
ADD, RUN, VOLUME, WORKDIR etc  

And then also need the build commmand that i will need to exectue.

then can i simply use : ...Workspace$ docker build . 

?

Comment: @oblivion if your dockerfile is not named Dockerfile (but mydockerfile), then you need to use the `-f` option: `docker build -f mydockerfile -t myimagename .`.

Comment: thanks. and in my scenario, what do i need to put into the ADD, COPY, RUN, CMD, WORKDIR commands so that i can build image for my "demo" sbt project ? I am very confused about how to integrate this dockerfile with my own sbt project or what changes i need to make in this dockerfile.

Comment: @oblivion imagine you have a brand new empty folder. Leaving docker aside for a moment, what you would copy in that folder, and what command would run from that folder in order for your sbt project to execute itself properly? Once you know that, you know what to ADD, COPY or RUN in your docker image.

Comment: Thanks, that was a great insight you gave.So, to be precise, i will have to provide instructions in **mydockerfile** to copy my entire sbt-project(from its location) in that empty folder or current context,  provide command as 'cd demo' and 'sbt run'. Am i right ? And what if i want the image to be built into its default docker location in my system  and not just my own empty folder ?

Comment: @oblivion then you need to ADD/COPY that folder in the path you want in your image.

Comment: @here "Because image size matters, using ADD to fetch packages from remote URLs is strongly discouraged; you should use curl or wget instead. That way you can delete the files you no longer need after they’ve been extracted and you don’t have to add another layer in your image."

Comment: @VonC what is sbt.sh ?

Comment: @ArjunKarnwal A launcher/runner script copied into the image and executed as CMD. For the actual content of that script: https://github.com/William-Yeh/docker-sbt/blob/master/sbt.sh

Answer (score 0):

You may view the docker file generated from plugin: [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager). Should improve your initial understanding. For demo read general docker tutorials not sticking to what you want actually run in it.

After sbt `docker:publishLocal` you'll get image name and a dockerfile in target folder. You may run the image with `docker run -i MY_NAME`.